# Background-color : linear gradient not working

Tags: html, linear-gradients

I have the below HTML code and I want a gradient block. But the gradient is not rendering on browser.

```css
div {
  height: 10px;
  background-color: linear-gradient(to right, #cc0099, #ff9933, #ff3399);
}
```

```html
<div>hi</div>
```

Can you please tell me what the issue is.

Thanks in Advance,
Nikhila

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It has to be `background-image`, not `background-color`, for gradients.

```css
div {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #cc0099, #ff9933, #ff3399);
}
```

```html
<div>hi</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

Please change the `background-color` to `background` to make the code affected.

```css
    div {
      height: 100px;
      width: 100px;
      display: block;      
      background: linear-gradient(to right, #cc0099, #ff9933, #ff3399);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

`linear-gradient` should be used in `background-image`

```css
div {
  height: 10px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #cc0099, #ff9933, #ff3399);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`linear-gradient` should be used along with the `height`.

```
background: linear-gradient(120deg,#2980b9,#8e44ad);
height: 100vh;
```